# select n samples from each category

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column, score, it is integers between 1 and 5 inclusive. 
I'm attempting to select n (2000 in this case) samples from each score. 
My own hacking and other SO question have led me to construct the following query:

```
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 1 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 2 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 3 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 4 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 5 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
```

This feels like the worst way of doing this, whats more is that when I run each query separately, it gives me 2k results as expected, but when I run this union, I get less than 10k rows 
i am looking for help optimizing this query a little, but more importantly i want to understand why is the union returning the wrong number of results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to why your query is returning the wrong number of results, I would bet your data is not `distinct` within the result set that gets returned with each individual query.  When using `union`, it returns the `distinct` rows across the entire result set.

Try changing it to `union all`:

```
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 1 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union all
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 2 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union all
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 3 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union all
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 4 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
union all
select * from (select text, score from data where score= 5 and LENGTH(text) > 45 limit 2000)
```

- [Here's a condensed demo showing the difference.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hDTd2mZPj9dMdTuiZTVMKf/1)

---

If you have a primary key such as an auto-increment, then here's another approach generating a `row_number` for each group of scores (this assumes an `id` primary key):

```
select text, score
from (
  select text, score, 
         (select count(*) from data b 
          where a.id >= b.id and 
                a.score = b.score and 
                length(b.text) > 45) rn
  from data a
  where length(text) > 45
  ) t
where rn <= 2000
```

Comment: did not even occur to me there may be duplicates, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default `UNION` compares all rows and return the distinct ones only. That's why you are receving less than 10k. As sgeddes says use `UNION ALL` instead to get all 10k rows always, including duplicates. You do want duplicate rows, don't you?